# which profile to choose in Code Signing before Archiving an app?

Tags: xcode, code-signing, provisioning

i read the App Store Submission Tutorial on how to submit an app to the app store. all was going well until i reached the Code Signing phase. in the tutorial it's said that:

```
From the Code Signing Identity pop-up menu, in the distribution provisioning profile section, choose the certificate that begins with “iPhone Distribution:” followed by your name.
```

and in my version of Xcode (latest version), i have the following:

[image]

i can't find the "distribution provisioning profile section" in the pop-up menu. any help on what to choose?

Note: i edited the pic to remove my name and stuff.. so the empty spaces are filled.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create an app id for this app?

From the screenshot it looks like you have the * (wildcard) and an app id called Simple Text Editor. If the app is not Simple Text Editor, then go create the app id for your app and then create the provisioning profile(s) for that app id. Once that is done, then the automatic profile selector will kick in because it will match the app id to the app settings (plist file).

Comment: okay i got two more questions:
1. i should use the pop-up menu of the code signing identity which automatically changes all it's child items?
2. do i have to create a unique APP Id for each app i want to submit ? can't i use the wildcard? if not then what's the wildcard for?

Comment: i don't understand what you are asking for part 1. On 2, as far as I know yes you need a separate id for each app you submit. I may be wrong on that part as some apps can do some sort of sharing. I don't think you can use * for all of your apps. The wildcard allows you to build your apps and when you are ready to deploy or submit, then you get your app id and switch that. Once you create an App ID it pretty much stays there (no delete option) so don't go crazy with them unless you are going to use them.

Comment: in the first question i mean that which pop-up menu i should adjust ? there's Code Signing Identity which has 4 other items which also have pop-sup menus (Debug - any ios sdk - release - any ios sdk) if i set the code signing identity it automatically changes the others. so which one should i set?

Comment: Set the code signing identity for debug and release. The release one should point to a provisioning profile used for the app store. The debug would be for developement. If you optionally add an ad-hoc profile you could duplicate the release one and calling it ad-hoc. Ad-hoc is for beta testing.